# Change default screenshot folder in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

By default, the screenshots saved by pressing Windows + PrintScreen are stored in My Pictures/screenshots

How can I change this default screenshot saving location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Symlinks** to replace that default location and use any other Folder in any drive as long as it is not a removable drive.

e.g. 
I want to use ***E:\UPLOADS\Screenshots*** folder as the `Win`+`PrnScr` destination folder.

So I proceed with the following steps:

**1. Delete or rename the existing default folder**
Make sure that **Screenshots** folder doesn't exist inside your ***My Pictures*** folder.

**2. Launch CMD as admin** : Press `Win`+`X` there you will find an item option to launch Command Line with Admin privileges and write the following command.

```
mklink /D %userprofile%\Pictures\Screenshots "E:\UPLOADS\Screenshots\"
```

And that's it, now you can see your screenshots inside that folder.

Optionally, you might want to reset the screenshot counter with the following command:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v ScreenshotIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

[**UPDATE**]

Easier than the method above. Just right click the Screenshots folder and on its properties dialog window, switch to Location tab and Move its actual location to any other you like, it might be another hard drive, another partition or another computer in your network. You can also revert to the default location.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this worked before Windows 8.1, but now if you move the "My Pictures/screenshots" folder, this changes the default screenshot saving location.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @micke, I believe it does - I'm pointing out that there is an easier way of resolving the authors issue than the currently accepted question, which is 3 years old now. I've attempted to improve the clarity of my answer.